# How to only get text when fetching data between elements using regex?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I'm extracting and breaking up the data from the `<strong></strong>` tags, take the following:

```
<li><strong>2</strong> apples</li>
<li><strong>5</strong> rotten oranges</li>
<li><b>3</b> pears</li>
<li><strong>4 and</strong><strong>5</strong> not working</li>
```

Right now it's getting everything between the first and last `<strong>` tag, but I don't want to return the inner html tag inside the match.

The array being returned is echoing the following: `4 and</strong><strong>5` but I just want `4 and 5` in the array and same line.

This is the regex I've come up with: `<(?:strong|b)>(.*)(?:<\/(?:strong|b)>)(.*)`

http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/lgH

Comment: Use a parser, not regex. `<(strong|b)>(.*?)<\/\1>` might be closer to what you want but is unreliable.

Comment: @chris85 already am using xpath, this is just for testing purposes for a smaller unrelated issue. Sadly that separates the 5 from the "4 and", I need it to be "4 and 5" on the same line, thank you though.

Comment: Why not pull each `li` then pull each `strong`/`b` inside and join each `li`s contents together, if multiple are present.

Comment: Yeah, I'll give it a go.

Comment: Good luck. Post back if you have issues, and add the new code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're fine looking through the results of each line recursively, putting a lazy quantifier fixes your issue. You also don't need the second capturing group

```
<(?:strong|b)>(.*?)(?:<\/(?:strong|b)>)
```

See here - https://regex101.com/r/pk7gVe/1/

Comment: I'm using the second capturing group for other purposes. I mentioned in the question that I needed the "4 and 5" in the same line though (same array), thanks for taking the time to reply though.

Comment: Ah fair enough, should of given it another scan. It's possible you may not be going around it the easiest way, perhaps if you included the full use case we can provide better insights.

Comment: I know, I'm sorry, sometimes we focus only on the issue at hand to make it easier for those helping and miss the fact that other smaller details would help paint a better picture.

Comment: In match 4, group 1, I'd like to have "4 and 5" together in the same group but without the strong tags inside, just the text https://regex101.com/r/pk7gVe/2